# A strong reference from a view controller to each of its top level views

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there a strong pointer from a view controller to each of its top level views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `UIViewController` documentation, yes.  It says:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *view
```

Comment: It's the default top level view. What if I crate another top level view?

Comment: What do you mean by "create another top level view"? A view controller only has one.

Comment: As stated, there's only one.  Other views are going to be in some view's `subviews` array, if they're in the view hierarchy, and the array will retain them.